# Putting Python Output into .xlxs File

Tags: python

The following code runs and does what it's supposed to do but I'm having trouble using the XlxsWriter module in Python in order to get some of the results into a .xlxs file. The goal is for the output to contain information from the function block_trial where it tracks each block and gives me the all_powers variable the corresponds with that trial. Installing the module into my user directory goes smoothly but it won't give me a file that gives me both sets of information.

At the moment, I'm using:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('SRT_data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
```

Widen the first column to make the text clearer.

```
 worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)
```

Add a bold format to use to highlight cells.

```
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
```

Write some simple text.

```
worksheet.write('A1', 'RT')
workbook.close()
```

But can't get any of my data to show up.

```
import random, math

num_features = 20
stim_to_vect = {}
all_stim = [1,2,3,4,5]
all_features = range(num_features)
zeros=[0 for i in all_stim]
memory=[]

def snoc(xs,x):
    new_xs=xs.copy()
    new_xs.append(x)
    return new_xs

def concat(xss):
    new_xs = []
    for xs in xss:
        new_xs.extend(xs)
    return new_xs

def point_wise_mul(xs,ys):
    return [x*y for x,y in zip(xs,ys)]

for s in snoc(all_stim, 0):
    stim_to_vect[s]= []
    for i in all_features:
        stim_to_vect[s].append(random.choice([-1, 1]))

def similarity(x,y):
 return(math.fsum(point_wise_mul(x,y))/math.sqrt(math.fsum(point_wise_mul(x,x))*math.fsum(point_wise_mul(y,y))))

def echo(probe,power):
    echo_vect=[]
    for j in all_features:
        total=0
        for i in range(len(memory)):
            total+=math.pow(similarity(probe, memory[i]),power)*memory[i][j]
        echo_vect.append(total)
    return echo_vect

fixed_seq=[1,5,3,4,2,1,3,5,4,2,5,1]
prev_states={}
prev_states[0]=[]
prev=0
for curr in fixed_seq:
    if curr not in prev_states.keys():
        prev_states[curr]=[]
    prev_states[curr].append(prev)
    prev=curr

def update_memory(learning_parameter,event):
    memory.append([i if random.random() <= learning_parameter else 0 for i in event])

for i in snoc(all_stim,0):
    for j in prev_states[i]:
        curr_stim = stim_to_vect[i]
        prev_resp = stim_to_vect[j]
        curr_resp = stim_to_vect[i]
        update_memory(1.0, concat([curr_stim, prev_resp, curr_resp]))

def first_part(x):   
    return x[:2*num_features-1]

def second_part(x):
    return x[2*num_features:]

def compare(curr_stim, prev_resp):
    for power in range(1,10):
        probe=concat([curr_stim,prev_resp,zeros])
        theEcho=echo(probe,power)
        if similarity(first_part(probe),first_part(theEcho))>0.97:
            curr_resp=second_part(theEcho)
            return power,curr_resp
    return 10,zeros

def block_trial(sequence):
    all_powers=[]
    prev_resp = stim_to_vect[0]
    for i in sequence:
        curr_stim = stim_to_vect[i]
        power,curr_resp=compare(curr_stim,prev_resp)
        update_memory(0.7,concat([curr_stim,prev_resp,curr_resp]))
        all_powers.append(power)
        prev_resp=curr_resp
    return all_powers
```

Comment: Can you add the part of the code in which you try to output what you want to your excel file?

Comment: The block_trial function. The idea is to have a spreadsheet that will collect the trial number and then give back the all_powers value for the particular trial.

Comment: I've had much more luck with openpyxl than xlsxwriter.  When you run everything, does it finish?  Is the spreadsheet blank?